# Section not showing on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My HeroSection is not showing on React, all i get is a blank page with just my navbar, heres my code.

I believe the problem is my video-2 file, but i've tried everything and still getting a blank page, HeroSection is rendering in a Home.js file and Home is rendering in App.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import '../App.css'
import { Button } from './Button';
import './HeroSection.css';

function HeroSection() {
  return (
    <div className='hero-container'>
      <video autoPlay muted loop src="/videos/video-2.mp4" />
        <h1>ADVENTURE AWAITS</h1>
        <p>What are you waiting for?</p>
        <div className='hero-btns'>
          <Button className='btns' buttonStyle='btn--outline'
          buttonSize='btn--large'>GET STARTED</Button>

          <Button className='btns' buttonStyle='btn--primary'
          buttonSize='btn--large'>WATCH TRAILER<i className='far fa-play-circle'/>
          </Button>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HeroSection;
```

My App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.js';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/pages/Home.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: is there any log in console you can share?

Answer (score 0):

use video in React should use `<source/>`

So you can try to edit code to:

```
<video muted loop autoplay>
  <source src={require('/videos/video-2.mp4')} type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

or the better way is import video first

```
import video from "./videos/video-2.mp4";
...
 <source src={video } type="video/mp4" />
```

Comment: now im getting this error:
Module not found: You attempted to import /videos/video-2.mp4 which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: @ManfredoRomán Try to put your video in src folder and import in correct path.